# Bezierpath button width issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uibezierpath, cornerradius

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
        }
```

I am using this function to give corner radius from particular side for `UIButton`. I am calling this function into `UITableViewCell` but I am having issue like **I gave constraint to button like its width is changing as per device width change for exa if device is iPhone 5 then its width is 159.5 acoordingly half of screen width.** but it is not changing and button is cutting from its width.

I am calling this function in `TableviewCell`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.btnWithdraw.roundCorners([.bottomRight], radius: 4.0)
        self.btnAddFund.roundCorners([.bottomLeft], radius: 4.0)
}
```

But here issue is like It is taking original frame as per given in storyboard viewcontroller and button is not taking width as per constraints.

Any help would appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: In iOS 9 the button has the inherent ability to round only specific corners, with no need for the mask.

Comment: ok  what should I do if my application has support of ios 8? @matt

Comment: Place your code inside , `drawReact`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that you are assuming that `layoutSubviews` will be called on the *cell* under all circumstances where the *button* is being laid out afresh. That might not be true.

To avoid that assumption, implement your entire masking in the button itself, along these lines:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    var whatCorners : UIRectCorner = [.bottomRight]
    var whatRadius : CGFloat = 4.0
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.roundCorners(self.whatCorners, radius: self.whatRadius)
    }
}
```

That way, you can give each button the desired values for `whatCorners` and `whatRadius` and the button will round itself.